# How to write a query to show results only for assets that have four values in the 4 labels?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a query to show labels and their values for Assets.
Labels must be ('Drive ID','Lube 1 Spec.','Lube 1 Vol.','Lube 2 Spec.','Lube 2 Vol.').
some records could have null values for some labels.
I would like to retrieve records only that got 5 labels for each asset with values in it.

```
select a.AssetTypeUserDefinedLabel AS Label, 
       v.AssetTypeUserDefinedValue AS Value, 
       v.AssetID
from AssetTypeUserDefined a 
   inner join AssetTypeUserDefinedValues v on 
a.AssetTypeUserDefinedID = v.AssetTypeUserDefinedID
where a.AssetTypeUserDefinedLabel in ('Drive ID','Lube 1 Spec.','Lube 1 
Vol.','Lube 2 Spec.','Lube 2 Vol.') 
  and v.AssetTypeUserDefinedValue <> ''
order by v.AssetID, a.SequenceNumber
```

output should look like this for each asset:

```
Label           Value                         AssetID
----------------------------------------------------------
Drive ID    020-D-073(A), 020-D-074(B)        79
Lube 1 Spec.    Chain - NSF H1 / ISO 1000     79
Lube 1 Vol. Spray Applied weekly              79
Lube 2 Spec.    Adjusters -                   79
Lube 2 Vol. At Service                        79
```

I'm trying to fetch records that have all 5 labels as shown below without null value.
so for each AssetID i get 5 records

[image: snapshot for required output]

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think it doesnt work?

Comment: Can you simplify this question & add more details on example, please?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, You need a simple having clause -

```
select a.AssetTypeUserDefinedLabel AS Label
      ,v.AssetTypeUserDefinedValue AS Value
      ,v.AssetID
from AssetTypeUserDefined a
inner join AssetTypeUserDefinedValues v on a.AssetTypeUserDefinedID = v.AssetTypeUserDefinedID
where a.AssetTypeUserDefinedLabel in ('Drive ID','Lube 1 Spec.','Lube 1 Vol.','Lube 2 Spec.','Lube 2 Vol.') 
and v.AssetTypeUserDefinedValue <> ''
group by a.AssetTypeUserDefinedLabel
        ,v.AssetTypeUserDefinedValue
        ,v.AssetID
having(distinct count v.AssetID) = 5 
order by v.AssetID
        ,a.SequenceNumber
```

Comment: Not really, I'm not trying to use Group by or Having.

Comment: Could you please check my snapshot ?

Comment: Does the above query, giving any error to you. If so, Can you please provide us some sample data in fiddle?